# Pluralsight Building Your First Game For Android And The PC Using Java

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

Im working on this curs, folow all steps but got error. Problem is

```
 public boolean playerShotTouches(Rectangle boundingBox) {
    Iterator<AnimatedSprite> i = shots.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        AnimatedSprite shot = i.next();
        if(Intersector.intersectRectangles(shot.getBoundingBox(), boundingBox))
        {
            i.remove();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

android studio report:

> Error:(108, 27) error: method intersectRectangles in class Intersector cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: Rectangle,Rectangle,Rectangle
>   found: Rectangle,Rectangle
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: The error message means that the method `intersectRectangles` needs **three** rectangles as parameters, but you are passing it only two rectangles (`shot.getBoundingBox()` and `boundingBox`).

Comment: Jesper, thanks for your time. Thats clear, dont have  declaration of  intersepction(from error report) but in cours video he declare only this two and game works fine(just cheked in curs final code thay have only 2 decleration. Can u tell me how to declare interspection(third rectangle)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the relevant code from the course? The intersectRectangles method has always take 3 Rectangles as parameters. The 3rd one is the intersection rectangle to the area of overlap. So your code could do something like this:

```
AnimatedSprite shot = i.next();
Rectangle myIntersection = new Rectangle();
if(Intersector.intersectRectangles(shot.getBoundingBox(), boundingBox, myIntersection))
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, with third rectangle game works. This is course code :

Comment: `public boolean playerShotTouches(Rectangle boundingBox) {
  return shotTouches(shots, boundingBox);
 }`

 `public boolean enemyShotTouches(Rectangle boundingBox) {
  return shotTouches(enemyShots, boundingBox);
 }

 private boolean shotTouches(List<AnimatedSprite> shots,
   Rectangle boundingBox) {
  Iterator<AnimatedSprite> i = shots.iterator();
  while(i.hasNext())
  {
   AnimatedSprite shot = i.next();
   if(Intersector.intersectRectangles(shot.getBoundingBox(), boundingBox))
   {
    i.remove();
    return true;
   }
  }
  
  return false;
 }`

Comment: I copy this final code, and still dont work, but when i add 3rd rectangele _myInteresection_  works fine. If u have time check course code and tell me is thay wrong or im doing somthing bad. Becouse for them this code works normal

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. The libgdx intersectRectangles method requires 3 Rectangle parameters. Maybe the course is using a modified version of the libraries (that would seem odd to me). In the example code, you don't actually use the values of the 3rd rectangle, so you don't need to explicitly create a myIntersection variable, this would work too: if(Intersector.intersectRectangles(shot.getBoundingBox(), boundingBox, new Rectangle()))